# Excepcion al llamar un Hilo desde otra clase

Tags: android, hilos, excepciones

Tengo un THREAD creado en mi MainActivity (llamado Menu_Main) y este lo quiero pasar a mi clase (Cls_Logeo) donde me logeo para que se conecte a través de un Switch, pero al darle click en el switch me genera un error, le hice seguimiento a mi Time_Stop y me muestra nulo, osea que no me esta llamando a mi hilo de la clase principal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta en mi clase a la que quiero pasar ese hilo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el error que me genera, en el seguimiento al TIM me bota nulo:
I/System.out: <<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>null

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código y los errores se incluyen como texto. Replicar errores desde una imagen es inviable.

Comment: Buenos días, lo que quiero es que el hilo que ejecute en mi clase principal activarlo al darle clic en mi Switch pero desde otra clase... si me pudieras ayudar por favor

Comment: te recomiendo utilizar AsynckTask ya que es un hilo propio para android, los thread son mas utilizados para procesos super cortos ya que si tarda demasiado va hacer que tu app se cierre inesperadamente... si pones el codigo no como imagen sino como texto te puedo ayudar con la generacion de un hilo pero en asynkTask el cual hace el mismo procedimiento y para ejecutarlo seria new hilo.execute(params);

Comment: Hola me puedes dar tu correo para poder comunicarme y pasarte mi código, es que es un poco extenso y si tambien leí sobre AsynckTask, pero soy nueva en esto, espero me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Preguntar acá incluye mostrar un ejemplo mínimo, verificable. No tiene sentido preguntar y revisarlo por fuera, si la respuesta no le va a servir a nadie en el futuro. Los detalles, por favor añadelos a la pregunta. Gracias! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes intanciar tu clase Time_Stop en tu clase Menu_activity ejemplo:

`static Time_stop tim= new Time_Stop()`

y mandarlo llamar en tu clase Cls_logeo de esta manera:

`Menu_Main.tim.conectar()`

O instanciar tu clase Time_Stop en la actividad Csl_Login:
de esta manera puedes mandar llamar los metodos de esa clase. ya que la excepción te esta diciendo que el objeto tim es nulo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si lo instancie y no hay problema, el problema ocurre cuando creo mi OnCheckedChangeListener por que lo que quiero es que al activar mi switch me haga la conexion con ese (que se conecte con el Time_Stop) no sale error ni nada, pero cuando lo ejecuto me dice que estoy llamando a un objeto nulo.

Comment: Veo que checas el estado de 2 objetos de tipo Time_Stop en tu clase Cls_login uno en la linea 57 y otro en la linea 117, pero en la linea 117 estas usando una variable que no as intanciado, ya que en la linea 114 tienes declarada tu variable pero no la instancias, seria mas fácil si colocaras el código completo de ambas actividades para poder replicar el error, saludos.

Comment: Hola Serna, es que ne la linea 117 es solo un System.out.println para mostrar que es lo que llama coca que cuando corre me muestra que esta referenciando a un objeto nulo, justo lo que me dices tu y si lo instacie arriba pero dentro del OnCreateView no me llama a nada y todo sale nulo.. que hago :(

Comment: Si pero como te comento en la linea 114 vuelves a declarar una variable tim por lo que dentro del metodo oncheckedchange estas utilizando esa variable, mi correo es jesussernacxc@gmail.com por si puedes enviarme el ejemplo completo para revisarlo mas a detalle y darte una respuesta mas concreta saludos.

Comment: okey :) gracias, revisalo por favor me salvarias la vida.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió de mucho :) Serna

Answer (score 0):

Mi codigo es el siguiente en el Main Activity (Menu_Main):
su estructura del hilo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1.- Variables:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Variables">
        int Nro=-1,Puerto=0,NumSer=0;
        Socket Client;
        ObjectOutputStream Enviar;
        ObjectInputStream Recibir;
        Clas_ArrayList Cls_Get_Obj;
        Clas_ArrayList Cls_Ret_Tip;
        boolean Ini_Hilo=true,Corriendo=false,DatEnv=false;
        String Server="";
        int Num_Conect=0;//num con quien se conecta
        int Num_Env=-1; //num proceso pedido
        // </editor-fold>
```

2.-Conectar

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Conectar">
        public void Conectar(String Serv,int Puert){
            Server=Serv;
            Puerto=Puert;
        }
        // </editor-fold>
```

3.- Time_Stop_Ini (inicializar el socket):

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Time_Stop_Init">
        public void Time_Stop_Init(int Nro){
            this.Nro=Nro;
            Corriendo=true;
            Num_Env++;
        }
        // </editor-fold>
```

4.- Run (importante (solo pongo lo importante por que es muy muy grande en verdad)):

```
public void run(){
            do {
                if(Corriendo){
                    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Switch">
                    System.out.println ("siiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii "+Cls_Met.CargarHoraReal ());
                    switch(Nro){
                        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="0 Conexion">
                        case(0):
                            System.out.println ("Acceso S:"+Server+" : P:"+Puerto);
                            try {
                                Client = new Socket ( InetAddress.getByName ( Server ), Puerto);
                                Enviar = new ObjectOutputStream ( Client.getOutputStream () );
                                Enviar.flush ();
                                Recibir = new ObjectInputStream ( Client.getInputStream () );
                                Nro = 1;
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Nro = 3;
                                Log.e ( "Socket Iniciando !!!", "SI: 1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B " + Cls_Met.CargarHoraReal () );
                                e.printStackTrace ();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Nro = 3;
                                Log.e ( "Socket Iniciando !!!", "SI: 2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C " + Cls_Met.CargarHoraReal () );
                                e.printStackTrace ();
                            }
                            break;
}
                    }else{
                        System.out.println ("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb "+Cls_Met.CargarHoraReal ());
                    }
                    // </editor-fold>
                    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Temporalizador">
                    try {
                        sleep ( 3000 );
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e("TCP SI client", "SI: InterruptedException No corriennnnndoooooo "+Cls_Met.CargarHoraReal ());
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                    }

                    // </editor-fold>
            }while (Ini_Hilo);
        }
        // </editor-fold>
```